# Javascript / Phonegap with SQLite insert bug?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, insert

I am building a Phonegap application currently targeted primarily for iOS 7+.

I have a local SQLite database that I am copying clean from server. Several of the tables are empty at this time (they will not always be empty). When I use the code below, the `result.insertId` value is not being populated, but only for the first row inserted into the tables. After the first row all the `insertId`values are correct.

```
db.transaction(function (tx1) {
   tx1.executeSql(insertSQL1, [arguments],
      function (t1, result1) {
          if (result1 != null && result1.rowsAffected > 0) {
              logMessage("Result1:" + JSON.stringify(result1));
              $.each(UserSelectedArrayOfItems, function (index, value) {
              db.transaction(function (tx2) {
                    tx2.executeSql(insertSQL2, [result1.insertId, value],
                         function (t2, result2) {
                              if (result2 != null) {
                                  logMessage("Result2: " + JSON.stringify(result2));
                              }
                         },
                         function (t2, error) {
                              logMessage("There was an error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
                         });
                    });
               });
              << Do app Navigation if all was ok >> 
          }
      },
      function (t, error) {
           logMessage("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
      });
});
```

While testing, both tables start empty. Zero rows. Both have an ID column with properties: `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`. The insert does work and it does get an ID of 1. The ID is correct in the table, but the `result.insertId` is undefined in the transaction success callback.

The `logMessage` function writes the strings out to file so I can debug/support the app. Example log messages when inserting 1 row to parent table (always only one to parent) and 2 rows to child table (could be 1 to n rows):

```
Result1: {"rows":{"length":0},"rowsAffected":1}
Result2: {"rows":{"length":0},"rowsAffected":1}
Result2: {"rows":{"length":0},"rowsAffected":1,"insertId":2}
```

Has anyone seen this behavior before? I am using the following plugin:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.millerjames01.sqlite-plugin" version="1.0.1" />
```

Comment: I have noticed you are using db.transactiion() inside the outer tx.executeSql() call. You could use tx.executeSql() within the outer call. Maybe thats the issue.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I found that when you are using a value from a result (or rows) the best practice is to first evaluate the value of object to a new variable, then pass the new variable to another function call and do the work there. As an update to my example:

```
db.transaction(function (tx1) {
   tx1.executeSql(insertSQL1, [arguments],
      function (t1, result1) {
          if (result1 != null && result1.rowsAffected > 0) {
              logMessage("Result1:" + JSON.stringify(result1));
              var newID = result1.insertId;
              $.each(UserSelectedArrayOfItems, function (index, value) {
                DoWork(newID, value);
               });
              << Do app Navigation if all was ok >> 
          }
      },
      function (t, error) {
           logMessage("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
      });
});


function DoWork(id, value){
   db.transaction(function (tx2) {
        tx2.executeSql(insertSQL2, [id, value],
             function (t2, result2) {
                  if (result2 != null) {
                      logMessage("Result2: " + JSON.stringify(result2));
                  }
             },
             function (t2, error) {
                  logMessage("There was an error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
             });
        });
    }
```

You'll need to add any checks or returns so you can confirm everything went as expected. But that's the overall gist of what fixed it for me.